# Quisiera saber cual es la explicacion de esta formula

Tags: python, condiciones, while, print, formato-condicional

```py
a=0
while True:
    print("help")
    a=a+1
    if a>2: 
        break
    if a>2: 
        continue
```

Y el resultado es
Help
Help
Help

por que solo se escribe 3 veces?

Comment: La fórmula `a = a + 1` realiza la suma del valor de `1` con `a` y el resultado se lo asigna a la variable `a`.

Comment: ¿Qué fórmula es la que te plantea dudas? Lo que has pegado no es ninguna fórmula sino un fragmento de código. Además difícil de leer por los asteriscos que has metido ¿podrías quitarlos por favor? Y reitero ¿qué fórmula es la que no entiendes? ¿O la pregunta es por qué sale "solo" 3 veces? ¿Cuántas esperarías tú que salieran?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Yo te preguntaria.. siguiendo tu codigo (que supongo lo hiciste, agarraste papel y lapiz y fuiste instruccion por instruccion haciendo lo que haria la computadora) que esperaste que hiciera tu codigo? cuantas veces escribiste la palabra help?

Answer (score 0):

desde el momento en que se inicia la ejecución se asigna a la variable a un valor de cero, desde allí se comienza un ciclo mientras y se le pasa como parámetro el valor booleano `True`; dando como resultado que el bucle pueda ejecutarse sin un fin establecido imprimiendo en consola el primer `help`, por consiguiente se incrementa el valor de la variable `a` y se evalúa si cumple la condición de ser mayor que 2; de ser verdadera la condición se rompería el ciclo `break` y finalizaría la ejecución, de lo contrario continuaría los ciclos faltantes hasta que se satisfaga la condición de `a>2`.

Ojo: cada vez que se ejecute la sentencia `continue` el ciclo volverá a iniciar, pero la variable `a` al estar fuera del ciclo solo seguirá incrementando su valor por cada iteracion.